# Tensorflow estimator: average_loss vs loss

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-estimator

In `tf.estimator`, what's the difference between `average_loss` and `loss`? I would have guessed from the names that the former would be the latter divided by the number of records, but that's not the case; with a few thousand records, the latter is about three or four times the former.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between `average_loss` and `loss` is that one reduces the **`SUM`** over the batch losses, while the other reduces the **`MEAN`** over the same losses. Hence, the ratio is exactly the `batch_size` argument of your `input_fn`. If you pass `batch_size=1`, you should see them equal.

The actual reported tensors depend on the particular type of `tf.Estimator`, but they are very similar, [here's the source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/head.py#L857) for the regression head (corresponds to `tf.DNNRegressor`):

```py
training_loss = losses.compute_weighted_loss(unweighted_loss, weights=weights,
                                             reduction=losses.Reduction.SUM)

mean_loss = metrics_lib.mean(unweighted_loss, weights=weights)
```

As you can see, they are computed from the same `unweighted_loss` and `weights` tensors. The same values are reported to tensorboard summary.

Answer (score 3):

The actual ratio is exactly `4.0`, which corresponds to the batch size.

When you train a network, you usually feed inputs as a batch.
In the [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.4/get_started/get_started) you refer to , the batch size is `4`, so the loss is the sum of the losses over the whole batch, while the average loss is the average of the losses over the whole batch.